# View must have a tag

Tags: android, data-binding, android-databinding, android-architecture-components, viewstub

I have an abstract BaseActivity in my library module:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //Normal method to inflate the layout
        mBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.base_view_stub_layout);
        AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
        if (mBinding != null && mBinding.viewStub != null && mBinding.viewStub.getViewStub() != null) {
            mBinding.viewStub.getViewStub().setLayoutResource(getLayoutId());
        }

        if (!hasStubInflated) {
            View inflatedView = mBinding.viewStub.getViewStub().inflate();
            //Abstract method
            onViewStubInflated(inflatedView, savedInstanceState);
            //Normal method to hide progress bar
            onViewStubInflated();
        }
        initControllers();
        handleViews();
        setListeners();
        restoreValues(savedInstanceState);
    }
```

The MainActivity from AppModule extends the BaseActivity of library module and hence, getting an abstract method to override:

**MainActivity extends BaseActivity**

```
private ActivityMainBinding mBinding;

@Override
    public int getLayoutId() {
        return R.layout.activity_main;
    }

@Override
    public void onViewStubInflated(View inflatedView, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (mBinding == null || mBinding.getRoot() != inflatedView) {
            mBinding = ActivityMainBinding.bind(inflatedView);
        }
    }
```

When I run the app, I am getting:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: view must have a tag
        at com.example.android.emailapp.DataBinderMapperImpl.getDataBinder(DataBinderMapperImpl.java:67)
        at androidx.databinding.MergedDataBinderMapper.getDataBinder(MergedDataBinderMapper.java:74)
        at androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil.bind(DataBindingUtil.java:199)
        at androidx.databinding.ViewDataBinding.bind(ViewDataBinding.java:693)
        at com.example.android.emailapp.databinding.ActivityMainBinding.bind(ActivityMainBinding.java:99)
        at com.example.android.emailapp.databinding.ActivityMainBinding.bind(ActivityMainBinding.java:87)
        at com.example.android.emailapp.login.MainActivity.onViewStubInflated(MainActivity.java:86)
        at com.library.android.common.ui.baseui.BaseActivity.onCreate(BaseActivity.java:52)
```

Note that I have layout tag in both xml of BaseActivity and MainActivity.

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54803137/view-must-have-a-tag-error-in-android-data-binding/54803371) with no success.

**Is *mBinding.viewStub.getViewStub().setLayoutResource(getLayoutId())* an issue in BaseActivity as it will try to get the layout from AppModule?** if it is that, how can I solve it?

*If you know the answer, please try to explain why this is happening along with the solution...*

**Already tried**

[View must have a tag error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54803137/view-must-have-a-tag-error-in-android-data-binding/54803371)

[What does it mean by view must have a tag error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53184433/what-the-actual-meaning-caused-by-java-lang-runtimeexception-view-must-have-a)

[How to use databinding for viewstub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34712952/android-data-binding-how-to-use-viewstub-with-data-binding)

Comment: Can you share your **base_view_stub_layout.xml** code?

Comment: this worked for me. https://stackoverflow.com/a/70887156/4075178

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the custom class as the root view of `your_layout.xml` then you must override all constructors of view

### your class

```
class MyCustomView : FrameLayout {
    constructor(context: Context) : super(context){
        ...
    }

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs){
        ...
    }
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr){
        ...
    }
}
```

### your layout

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <data>
        <variable name="viewModel" type="......" />
    </data>

    <MyCustomView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </MyCustomView>

</layout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must wrap your viewStub's layouts with `<layout></layout>` as well, which is what they are expecting : Either using DataBinding everywhere, or simply nowhere.

---

If you don't want DataBinding on the viewStub, then extra work needs to be done.

For example if `itemData` is the DataBindingImpl object for my listview, and I am to inflate some sort of `more options` overlay-ViewStub, then I need to store the inflated view myself, and avoid accessing the `mRoot field of the DataBinding's ViewStubProxy

```
ViewGroup inflated = (ViewGroup) itemData.someView.getTag();
if(inflated==null) {
    ViewStub stub = itemData.viewStubProxy.getViewStub();
    if(stub!=null) {
        stub.setOnInflateListener(null);
        inflated = (ViewGroup) stub.inflate();
        // what I need is simply to set onClickListener on all of it's children. (one for-loop inside)
        Utils.setOnClickListenersOneDepth(inflated, onClickListener, 3, null);
        itemData.someView.setTag(inflated);
    }
}
if(inflated!=null) {
    // what I need then is to animate the overlay. 
    View mRoot = inflated;
    int width = itemData.getRoot().getWidth();
    mRoot.setAlpha(0);
    mRoot.setTranslationX(width/3);
    mRoot.animate().alpha(1);
    mRoot.animate().translationX(0);
}
```

Never invoke `itemData.viewStubProxy.getViewStub().getRoot()`、`.isInflated()` or so because we are now storing the `inflated` outside of the DataBindingImpl object.